# How to add a reducer to a React Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers

I have the following store:

**setup.js**

```
import catReducer from '../reducers/catReducer';

let store;

const initStore = ({onRehydrationComplete}) => {
  store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      catReducer,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer()
    }),
    {},
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history),
        apolloClient.middleware()
      ),
      autoRehydrate()
    )
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [
      'form'
    ]
  }, onRehydrationComplete);

  return store;
};
```

I'm trying to add the reducer `catReducer` as seen above. When `catReducer` is not present everything works, when I add `catReducer` and later log the `state` in a component the catReducer is not being shown as expected in the store. What am I doing wrong?

**catReducer.js**

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function catReducer(state = initialState.cats, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_CATS_SUCCESS:
      return action.cats
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**initialState**

```
export default {
  cats: [],
  hobbies: []
}
```

**My react component: CatsPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CatList from './CatList';
import {loadCats} from '../../actions/catActions';

class CatsPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadCats())
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cats</h1>
        <div>
          <CatList cats={this.props.cats} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CatsPage.propTypes = {
  cats: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {

  console.log('mapStateToProps')
  console.log(state)

  return {
    cats: state.cats
    //cats: [{id:1, name: "Maru"}]
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CatsPage);
```

### Updates

JS console errors with the above:

```
warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `cats` is marked as required in `CatsPage`, but its value is `undefined`.

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `cats` is marked as required in `CatList`, but its value is `undefined`.

CatList.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: It's state.catReducer. http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/

Comment: thanks but where in the above?

Comment: In combineReducers you set the key to catReducer. If you want it to be cats make it cats: catReducer.

Comment: when I update combineReducers to `cats: catReducer,` and then later output console.log(state) I see the cats object but the object has an error and exception: Internal Server Error, exception: #<ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template public/index.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js,....

Comment: Issue with the API? Check out the loadcats.

Comment: the app is breaking before loadcats even gets called...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `mapStateToProps` you tried to asign cats to `state.cats` but in your `combineReducers` function your object looks like
`{catReducer: catReducer}`.
Try to change in your `combineReducers` function the `catReducer` entry to somethings like `{cats: catReducer}`

Comment: Are you suggesting changing `catReducer,` to `cats: catReducer,` ?

Comment: When I do that, I get an error, see above comment... thanks

Answer (score 1):

modify your `combineReducers` calling. See line no 3 of both code samples.

**Correct One**

`combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      cats: catReducer,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer()
    })`

**Your One will be translated like**

`combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      catReducer: catReducer,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer()
    })`

Comment: Thanks but when I output the state in the mapStateToProps, I see the state object having a cats: object and when I open that open there is a cats Array. there shouldn't be a cats OBJECT > cats Array(0) right?

Comment: No, you are returning an array from your reducer so you will get an array in cats object.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
 return {
    cats: state.cats
    //cats: [{id:1, name: "Maru"}]
  };
```

to

```
  return {
    cats: state.catReducer.cats
    //cats: [{id:1, name: "Maru"}]
  };
```

might do the trick for you

Comment: changing it to `cats: state.cats.cats` did fix the error which is good but structurally, we don't want cats within cats,,, how can I make it just cats and not cats > cats?

Comment: the thing is that you are using combine reducers here, which means there will be one root reducer which is a combination of multiple reducers, and your cats object is not in the root reducer, here, your root reducer is made up of combining multiple reducers(cats being one of them), in a parallel world if you just had one reducer, which would be the cat reducer, you could have used `state.cats` for that, but where the root reducer comes into play it goes as `state`->`rootReducer`->`individualReducer`. Hope this makes sense.